# iOS Safari's Home Screen app blocked by Google OAuth

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, google-oauth

When I use my app in iOS Safari, it makes the complete OAuth flow with Google without problem, opening a new windows or tab, and closing it after the login.

But when I add the same page to Home Screen, I started the app in flow screen and try to make the Login, the flow now is blocked.  I have been offering this app for three years and I have 50.000 users.  Since yesterday my gmail users can't login... Facebook login flows and linkedIn flow for OAuth works without problem with my app.

Only Google in iOS  have this problem.  In Android 4.4, until now, the home screen app works perfects with the OAuth2 flow.

I read this article but it doesn't solve the case of Web Apps or Full Screeen web apps or Home Screens apps:
https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html
We need a JAVASCRIPT SOLUTION, not a native Android or iOS.

I need Google to don't interpret full screen's Safari apps as webviews, this is an error for me.  This is the same engine as Safari but without controls.  The user agent must be treated the same as Safari's, because it's the same.  May be apple must send the same useragent in both cases.

Anyone has this same problem and has a solution that doesn't involve to create a native app or cordova app?

Comment: I guess it is because Google recently changed there login workflow.

Comment: Any news from Google or Apple?  I think this could be solved, it's not an embedded webview, is the normal Safari full screen... If Apple could sent the same user agent headers this will be solved.

Comment: Nobody else having this issue with full,screen web apps? Any workaround?